# Are there trials of finding a general solution for polynomials of $n^{th}$ degree with other operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra

It seems they tried to find solutions for the general polynomial of $n^{th}$ degree using only the coeficients, and roots, sums, subtractions, multiplication and division. Until Abel gave the proof that it was impossible. Are there trials of doing it with another operators? For example, some days ago I've read about [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). Which also points to [hyperoperations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) - has anyone tried to use one of those?

Comment: Hyperoperations are derived from the usual algebraic operations, so you won't get far with them. It is more interesting to ask for solutions which involve trigonometric functions, exponentials, logarithms etc.

Comment: Yes. I also thought about that. But I thought that perhaps there may be operations not derived from the usual algebraic operations.